# Jquery Load global function partially working

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, load

Here is the code.

```
function product_analysis_global() {

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    $('#product_' + this.alt).load(this.title);
    $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).value = this.value;
});
}
```

All working except the last line that is not working, any ideas. Should return the value of the current checkbox to the appropriate field `'#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt`

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.value` isn't a jQuery object property (it's a DOM object one), it should be [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
$('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val(this.value);
```

Or (more for illustration), the direct jQuery-less DOM method:

```
document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).value = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val()` function.

```
var $this = $(this)
$('#product_quantity_PRI_' + $this.attr('alt')).val($this.val());
```

Comment: Just because you *can* use an abstraction doesn't mean you *should*...these are basic DOM properties, why not fetch them that way? It's less expensive as well :)

Comment: You are right - I would in my code. But this is the very thing Robin Knight is confused on. So for consistency I use val() in all cases in this answer.